# JSON_HEX_AMP option required for Laravel LengthAwarePaginator->toJson() when used as Vue.js component prop?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vue-component

Here's the super short version of what's happening, as far as I can tell. Debugging this has been a pain, and I'm not sure if this is a Laravel issue or a Vue.js issue (leaning toward Vue.js). Here goes...

I'm using a LengthAwarePaginator object to retrieve data to pass to a Vue.js component as a property. (This is unorthodox, and I plan to convert it to a fetch() method in the component when I have a proper API set up.)

```
<my-component :items="{{ $paginator->toJson() }}"></my-component>
```

When my `$paginator` data contains an item with a string field that contains `&quot;` -- e.g. `Plumber cut pipe 4&quot; from end` -- Vue.js completely fails to render my component.

However, if instead of `&quot;` the field uses a raw `"`, everything works just fine -- e.g. `Plumber cut pipe 4" from end`.

I was alerted to this issue by a Vue.js parse error: `avoid using JavaScript keyword as property name: "for" in expression ...`. I believe I received this error because of subsequently broken syntax that made a string use of 'for' look like a property name.

It's almost like Vue.js is double-converting the resulting `&amp;quot;` to `"` when it reads the property, and the resulting extra `"` turns string data into a property name. This makes no sense though, since the raw `"` allows proper parsing.

My work-around, while I try to understand why this is even broken at all, has been to assign my property like this:

```
<my-component :items="{{ $paginator->toJson(JSON_HEX_AMP) }}"></my-component>
```

Does anyone understand why this is happening? Why is this an unsafe string in this context: `Plumber cut pipe 4&quot; from end` ???

Comment: I have not tested this for Eloquent Collections and Models, but Model uses the same basic toJson() setup while Collection is only a little different.

Comment: Also, I'm using Vue.js 2.2.4.